# Permutations of multiple ranges of numbers

Tags: c++, vector, permutation

I need to generate permutations from multiple ranges of numbers in array.

```
using namespace std;

int generatePermutations(vector<int> &myVector, vector<vector<int> > &swappable) {
    int i = 0, s = 0;
    for (s = 0; s < swappable.size(); s++) {
        do {
            for (i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
                printf("%i ", myVector[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            swappable.pop_back();
            generatePermutations(myVector, swappable);
        } while (next_permutation(myVector.begin()+swappable[s][0],
                myVector.begin()+swappable[s][1]));
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> myArray;
    myArray.resize(6);
    myArray[0] = 0;
    myArray[1] = 1;
    myArray[2] = 2;
    myArray[3] = 3;
    myArray[4] = 4;
    myArray[5] = 5;

    // Swappable positions (0 - first, 1 - last)
    vector<vector<int> > swappable;
    swappable.resize(2);
    swappable[0].resize(2);
    swappable[0][0] = 1; swappable[0][1] = 3;
    swappable[1].resize(2);
    swappable[1][0] = 4; swappable[1][1] = 6;
    generatePermutations(myArray, swappable);

    return 0;
}
```

The example above should generate something like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 2 1 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 5 4
0 2 1 3 5 4
```

But it generates this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: What is `swappable` for?  Why are there no comments in your code?

Comment: Comment added. swappable is for holding first and last positions, between them i need to generate permutations.

Comment: Ok.  Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger to see *why* it always gives the same result?

Comment: I am very confused by this. I do not understand what you are trying to do, and I fail to see the pattern in the example you provide. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm surprised it generated anything at all, your algorithm does not make sense, you are calling `pop_back()` on the `swappable` vector, which means after the first recursive call, it contains nothing, and the while loop will access invalid items...

Comment: If this isn't homework I am surprised that std::next_permutation` hasn't been mentioned... I really hope this is homework... `;)`

Comment: @rubenvb: Next_permutation has been in the question since the first revision.

Comment: @Fred: wow, must have missed that. Something with forests and trees `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it swappable is a set of ranges which may be swapped?  So [[1, 3], [4, 6]] means anything in [1, 3) (indexes 1 and 2) can be swapped around in that range, and similarly for [4, 6)?  Is it also true that the ranges will never overlap?

[How does this look:](http://ideone.com/Z6XWl)

```
typedef vector<vector<int> >::const_iterator SwappableIter;
void generatePermutations(vector<int> &data,
                          SwappableIter begin, SwappableIter end)
{
  if (begin == end) {
    print(data);
  }
  else {
    vector<int>::iterator start = data.begin() + (*begin)[0],
      stop = data.begin() + (*begin)[1];
    sort(start, stop);
    do {
      generatePermutations(data, begin + 1, end);
    } while (next_permutation(start, stop));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, ranges will never overlap.

Comment: If `swappable` is supposed to be a vector of ranges, use an `std::pair` or a custom `struct` rather then a nested vector.

Comment: Yes, a pair would be better; I kept the type from the question for my example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of your generation algorithm (which is broken).

```
int generatePermutations(vector<int> &myVector, vector<vector<int> >& swappable) {
  do
  {
    do
    {
      print(myVector);
      // generate permutations of the second segment
    } while(next_permutation(myVector.begin() + swappable[1][0], myVector.begin() + swappable[1][1]));

    // re-sort the second segment
    sort(myVector.begin() + swappable[1][0], myVector.begin() + swappable[1][1]);

    // calculate permutation of first segment
  } while(next_permutation(myVector.begin() + swappable[0][0], myVector.begin() + swappable[0][1]));
}
```

EDIT: fixed now to generate the combinations, but only works for two ranges, Fred's solution above is more scalable..

Comment: This does not scale well; e.g. when swappable.size() == 10.

Comment: @Fred, erm that would be because you've set the ranges up incorrectly rather than anything wrong with the above function!

Comment: @Nim: How have they been setup incorrectly?  That's been copied directly from the way they are setup in the question.  Did you also notice the compiler warning?

Comment: @Nim: How do you know [1, 3) isn't correct?  It matches the desired output listed in the question.  Even accepting what you call the "incorrect input", your code's results *don't match what you describe!*  Do you see how the 3rd and 4th lines of output are identical?

Comment: @Fred, was just about to update my comment.. :) well if you select [1,3), then that only gives you two items, for example, (1,2), the only other possible combination is (2,1) - which the above generates, and same for range [4,6) (4,5) -> (5,4), so the output is only going to show that - in that sense, the above is correct (unless I'm missing some other combinations), and I'm printing out the intermediate steps as well. The output: `0 2 2 3 5 4` cannot be a possible permutation...

Comment: @Nim: Compare the [output of my code](http://ideone.com/Z6XWl) to [your code](http://ideone.com/qTuew).  Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Fred, ah, missed the bit that said for every permuation of the first range, generate all the permutations of the second range...

Answer (score 0):

You have created a seemingly correct iterative solution for the problem, but in each iteration, you remove an element from the `swappable` vector and make a recursive call.
As both `myVector` and `swappable` are passed by non-`const` reference, these recursive calls destroy the contents of the `swappable` vector before you are actually generating permutations.

Just remove the lines

```
swappable.pop_back();
generatePermutations(myVector, swappable);
```

and the code should start to work.

Comment: The code in the question, after removing the two lines you mention, does not work.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Care to explain in what way it fails to work? Or do you mean the missing `#include` statements? When executing the code with the required `#include`s added and the lines I mentioned commented out, I get a result that is similar to what @Radek listed as expected.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/4GHv0.  Note the UB due to the last warning, how the four output lines have one line duplicated, and how one line is missing from the expected output.  (And BTW, it wasn't my downvote; I don't downvote.)

Comment: @Fred: Fair enough. But it is hard to match the listed output exactly (you also did not do that), given that on the last line the `1` is replaced by a `2`.